# Opening a file FileNotFoundException with scanner in Java, Eclipse, Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, ubuntu, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a parser to a file called "x". I want to use scanner. I tryied to follow actions from a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RNYUKxAgmw.

```
package q;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parser {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("/home/x/eclipse-workspace/q/src/q/x.txt"));
        String s=x.nextLine();
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

The file that I want to open is called "x", its text file. We can see it in Package Explorer on left side. I clicked right on its properties. There is visible file locatization.

There appears F**ileNotFoundException** as on the picture. I doesn't understand why this file cannot be opened.

[image]

[image]

[update] But I'm not sure if this is what

Comment: use the absolute path, not quite familiar with linux directory structure but in something like windows the beginning of the an absolute path starts with the drive letter like c:\ or d:\ all the way to the file location

Comment: If the file is named `x`, why do you use `x.txt` in your code?

Comment: It's this file type extension. I tried `Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("/home/x/eclipse-workspace/q/src/q/x"));` but there is still
`Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Precisely.

Comment: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: That's a **compilation** error. Google for "Java exception tutorial", and read how to deal with exceptions in Java.

Comment: I should use `try{}catch(){}` formula. But file still is not opened.

Comment: How can you know that, since your code doesn't compile, and thus can't possibly run? Fix all your compilation errors, then compile and run your code.

Comment: Don't ignore the Exception in the catch block - call `e.printStackTrace()` to find out exactly what the error is.

Comment: And again, your file is named `x`, not `x.txt`.

Comment: It worked when I changed to `x` and when I wrote `throws Exception`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There appears FileNotFoundException as on the picture. I doesn't
>   understand why this file cannot be opened.

That's not what's happening. The error is in compilation time (the program has not executed, it doesn't know if the file -will- exist). The compiler is telling you "this method/constructor, according to its declaration, can throw an Exception (in this case: a FileNotFoundException ) at run time; you have not told me what to do in that case".

You really need to read about how Exceptions are treated in Java.

For a quick remedy, add a `throws Exception` to your `main` declaration. (Bear in mind: that is an awful thing to do if you don't really understand what are you doing)